# Не работает функция htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

Добрый день всем. Не работает функция htmlspecialchars

```
$description = htmlspecialchars($all_array["characteristical"][$index],  ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') ;
```

Вроде бы стоит, что бы в UTF-8 записывало в базу, но конвертирует он сам по себе почему-то в windows-1251 файл в utf-8, строка в базе в utf8_general_ci

Comment: Функция htmlspecialchars() не может конвертировать из одной кодировки в другую! Проверяйте в какой кодировке поступают ваши данные.

Answer (score -1):

1. Проверьте параметр default_charset в настройках php
2. А лучше всего чтобы входные данные были уже в UTF-8